# In PowerShell, how to tell if a directory "delete" op will succeed?

Tags: powershell, directory

I'm writing a PowerShell script that will, if possible, delete an occasional extraneous directory if a subtask (over which I have no control, apart from invoking it) fails to properly delete it.

The catch is that the directory (which has a lot of files and recursive hierarchy) may or may not be in use by another (large, 3rd party) program. Normally, I'm doing this in Windows Explorer: I hit the "delete" key, I get a "in use" dialog, shrug and move on, no harm done. (It's a big process and it usually cleans up after itself.)

What I *don't* want to do is call `Remove-Item -Recursive` and have it purge half a directory and then discover that some random file is in use. Nor am I even sure it's a file-in-use issue; maybe it's because the directory (or a subdirectory) is some process's current directory or, for some reason, the directory (or subdirectory) itself is open (I'm just making stuff up at this point), or some entirely different and mysterious cause.

I'm hoping to duplicate the current manual process.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Basicaly, I'm looking for `Remove-Directory-If-You-Can-But-Don't-Do-Anything-At-All-If-You-Can't`.

---

(Edit)

Note that I don't want to remove *anything* in the directory if the directory is still "in use", in some sense. That will corrupt the large process using the directory. If the large process has finished and moved on, I can delete the directory.

---

(Edit)

This? https://github.com/pldmgg/misc-powershell/blob/master/MyFunctions/PowerShellCore_Compatible/Get-FileLockProcess.ps1

Called recursively? (Not sure if it'll work for subdirs, but I can experiment.)

Comment: So, since `Remove-Item -Recursive` can break half way removing the files, you could `Get-ChildItem -Recursive | Remove-Item`. That should do the trick

Comment: Note that I don't want to remove *anything* unless the whole thing will succeed. Not sure that's true of ``ls -rec | rm``.

Comment: _"I hit the "delete" key, I get a "in use" dialog, shrug and move on, no harm done."_ as far as I know when you do this, Windows starts deleting until it finds a file in use by a process so, harm was done

Comment: Hmm, so that means the initial directory itself must be open by the other large process? I do see Windows going through some discovery process before it starts deleting; maybe it finds the problem then? (I haven't observed it that closely; just assuming Microsoft magic is happening.)

Comment: Definitely that script you posted can help you know if you would help you know if any process has a handle over some of the files (but probably requires run as admin). Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle

Answer (score 1):

Could try moving the items away somewhere safe first, and restore items that were successfully moved if anything goes wrong.

If you move things to a folder in the path for temp files, you don't have to delete them - the system will delete them sometime after your process releases the handle on the new folder.

Simple case:

```
$tempRoot = Split-Path (New-TemporaryFile).FullName
$tempDir  = New-Item "$tempRoot\$(New-Guid)" -Type Directory

Move-Item "$HOME\Downloads\SomeFolder\" $tempDir
```

If anything is holding a file handle in the folder being moved, it will fail and the move won't occur.

Deleting several files and folders:

```
$tempRoot = Split-Path (New-TemporaryFile).FullName
$tempDir  = New-Item "$tempRoot\$(New-Guid)" -Type Directory

try {
    Move-Item "$HOME\Downloads\*" $tempDir.FullName -ErrorAction Stop
    Remove-Variable tempDir
} catch {
    Move-Item "$($tempDir.FullName)\*" "$HOME\Downloads"
}
```

`Move-Item` will move whole folders as given above, so no need for recursion.

The move operation should be quick, assuming the files/folders you're moving are on the same drive as the temp folder. The files themselves don't have to be physically moved on disk. The OS just modifies an entry in a table. Moving an entire folder only requires one update (not one for each file within it).

If the above doesn't satisfy your needs, maybe check out this article: [How to Manage Open File Handles with PowerShell](https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/2956/how-to-manage-open-file-handles-with-powershell/).